# How do I properly set up Subsurface Scattering for a human skeleton for Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, subsurface-scattering

I have a 3D-model of a human skeleton with 8K textures and would like to properly set up Subsurface Scattering and the materials. I've looked around but I'm a little confused about which sockets to connect to which map etc.
Here's a download link for the mesh and all textures: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tlawz8o55cngdaq/HumanMaleSkeleton1.zip?dl=0
If anyone could give me an example of how to set up the materials as good and physically accurate as possible with the maps I have I would really appreciate it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under the green label on the right with `Principled BSDF` turn up `Subsurface` for subsurface scattering; also adjust the `Subsurface` color. You can also increase the `Subsurface Radius` very slightly.

According to the following answers: [Principled BSDF subsurface scattering values for skin material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121037/principled-bsdf-subsurface-scattering-values-for-skin-material) the bones should probably have a subsurface value of less than 0.1. How accurate that looks mostly will depend on the lighting and your own ability to reference an image.

Because subsurface scattering varies depending on the distance from the edge of perceived light, along with the distance traveled through the mesh, I don't believe you need to map its value.