# Subsurface scattering field

Tags: shaders

I have color A and color B and you want sub surface scattering.  My question is, on the "thickness" map, does pure white represent complete translucency or does grey?

White would mean I'm taking 100% of color B right?  Which means color A will not be present at all which isn't translucent.  So my guess is .50 (grey) is the true value if you want both colors?  Or am I wrong?

I already tried this with principle shader with red and blue creating purple with .5 (grey) sub surface scattering:

[image: 50% scattering]

If I have white, I would be taking 100% of color B, thus there is no translucency with the red.

[[image: Completely color B[2]]

So my basic question is, when I make a sub surface scattering map, should I be using grey for max translucency?  Or is there something I'm missing here?  Because I have seen White areas in thickness maps before which makes no sense to me, you're just taking 100% of color B?

Comment: Hello :). The slider doesn't simply mix the two colors. It works as a multiplier for the Subsurface Radius values. So having it at 1 often makes sense. [Blender Manual - Principled BSDF](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html)

Comment: Thanks the math makes sense but I don't understand why color A would vanish completely when set to max...   If they colors simply don't "mix", wouldn't I see some traces of the red?

Comment: Hello :). This is a special case where you're using pure RGB Blue so only blue channel is available. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Subsurface is 1, the Base color has no influence.
Still you can use  *radius* to extract different colors from the *Subsurface color*.

**Why it doesn't work for you**
You're using RGB Blue (0,0,1), so Red and Green cannot be extracted (as they're zero).

**Example**
I'm using some random Blue containing all three channels (RGB: 0.14, 0.19, 0.8):

- Subsurface = 1 (so the base color has zero influence)
- I can bring up plenty of Red from my Blue, using the *Subsurface Radius*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jachym, what value would be recommended for skin?  Probably not 1..

Comment: Hello :). This thread could help: [Principled BSDF subsurface scattering values for skin material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/121037/). Also the Subsurface Radius will be rather important.